# Process.GetProcesses() taking too much of CPU utilization

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, winforms

I'm using the following code in my windows application, I'm calling this method to find another process is running or not, the problem is, whenever I am calling this method my PC CPU utilization increase by 18-25%. Any other way to find the running process in windows? Thanks in advance.

`Process[] runningProcessFromCurrentSession = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.SessionId == Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId && p.ProcessName.Equals(TrackerAgent.Modal.Constants.Pmdriver)).ToArray();`

Comment: If you need current process you can use `Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();`

Comment: @AndreyBelykh I need another process, not a current process

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign this expression to a variable:

```
var currentProcessId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId;

Process[] runningProcessFromCurrentSession = 
Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.SessionId == 
currentProcessIdd &&   p.ProcessName.Equals(TrackerAgent.Modal.Constants.Pmdriver)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId` to variable outside of the `Where` clause, otherwise `Process.GetCurrentProcess()` will be executed for every process found by `GetProcesses`, which can lead to high CPU usage:

```
var sessionId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId;
Process[] runningProcessFromCurrentSession = Process
    .GetProcesses()
    .Where(p => p.SessionId == sessionId && p.ProcessName.Equals(TrackerAgent.Modal.Constants.Pmdriver))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning I think, that this is a trap within which it is easy to fall when using `Linq`... It helps _**fast**_ prototyping, but it also helps to _**quickly**_ produce _**slow code**_... :P Whenever performance is needed, it is often better to write a loop oneself... It makes one have to think twice, declare variables, etc... And the result is often _(if you do it contentiously)_ far better... ;)